# What's the difference between the LG G6 model numbers h870, h870s, h870k and h870v?

Tags: lg

I am considering to buy a LG G6.
I am living in Germany and when I did some research, I found that the model number of the G6 version sold in Europe is 'h870'.
But I also found that there are the model numbers 'h870s', 'h870k' and 'h870v' out there.
As I wasn't able to find any difference between those four on the web, I wanted to ask if anyone could please help me with this and point out the differences (if there are any).

**EDIT**
Apparently there was a typo in one of my sources and there isn't a V model but a L model.
https://www.techwalls.com/lg-g6-model-numbers-differences/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suffix variants are meant for different regions and carriers around the world, mostly for support of different regional LTE bands.

From PDAdb: [H870](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=11183&c=lg_h870_g6_td-lte__lg_diva) supports 14 bands; [H870S](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=11426&c=lg_h870s_g6_lte-a__lg_diva) supports 8; [H870K](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=11357&c=lg_h870k_g6_td-lte__lg_diva) only supports 5. I don't see a "V" variant listed (it's against the naming norm of LG, actually).

AFAIK, Europe uses LTE Band 20 primarily, so both H870 and H870S should do the job locally just fine, but considering international roaming capabilities, H870 is the one you want to get if you do have the money to shell out (EU variants are almost always the most expensive).

**One more thing**: if you want to tinker with the phone at all (even just rooting, even not immediately), buy the EU variant without hesitation. Only EU (H870) and US Open (US997) variants will ever get official bootloader unlock from LG - not even the Australian variant (which also bears H870 with no suffix).

Comment: The EU models aren't only expensive, they also don't have wireless charging, 64 GBs internal storage, Quad-DAC, etc. .

Comment: What about the DS (dual SIM) model?

Comment: Sure, this year LG has a really strange release strategy (you know they pushed out a "G6+" recently that adds those perks but doesn't change that Snapdragon 821).

Comment: The [DS variant](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=11421&c=lg_h870ds_g6_dual_sim_td-lte_64gb__lg_diva) seems to have the same band support as the non-suffixed version. Needless to say it can't be BL unlocked either (or I would've bought myself one already).

Comment: @AndyYan There is an H870V version (at least in Brazil). It is called LG G6 Dual thanks to being able to have two Nano-SIM cards. Still with a Snapdragon 821 but with 64GB of internal storage. I have a photo of a demo displayed in a store selling those very H870V. And, despite not being able to use photos, I think this will serve as proof: https://lg-firmwares.com/lg-h870v-firmwares/

Comment: @José Thanks for letting know - I didn't find valid mentions of the V model at the time I wrote the answer.